# How change circular progress bar in QML Dial?

Tags: qt, qml, progress-bar, qt5

I have a problem with changing progress bar color in QML Dial Component. I tried to use Canvas but finally i did nothing. Any suggestions or examples?

```
Dial {
    value: 0.5
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
}
```

black progress bar

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in [this another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48303428/6622587) you can use palette, for this you can check the [source code](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/src/imports/controls/Dial.qml), so the solution is:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Dial {
        // @disable-check M17
        palette.dark: "red"
        value: .5
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to change the color of an Item is ColorOverlay, which has RGBA support.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-coloroverlay.html#details

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Dial {
        id: dial
        value: .5
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }

    ColorOverlay {
        anchors.fill: dial
        source: dial
        color: "#80800000"
    }
}
```